# Is there a way to do in-place member construction in C++ (without copying and destructing an object)?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy

So, I finally tracked down a strange crash in my software, which is happening because of an issue that I've run into before:

```
m_member = Foo(var1, var2)
```

Which I've realized is performing a construction of Foo using var1 and var2, assigning this instantiation of Foo to m_member via a copy assignment, and then is deleting the original instance. Is there a way to avoid this behavior and have something akin to:

```
m_member(var1, var2);
```

I know this is possible to do in initializer lists, but I am unfortunately modifying this member for an object that is already constructed. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried writing a move-assignment operator for `Foo`?

Comment: (Why would that cause a crash anyway? :-/)

Comment: Your copy/assignment functions either have side-effects, or not coded correctly.   Either way, a bug means your objects do not have correct copy semantics, but you're using it in copying operations.

Comment: @cigien Yes, sorry, I'm bad with words sometimes. And I tried wrapping up Foo in a std::move(Foo(var1, var2)) type of way, but that didn't seem to do much of anything.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, I'm aware, which is why I'm trying to avoid the copy altogether. These objects are meant to encapsulate OpenGL buffers, which are inadvertently getting destroyed and reinitialized when the copy assignment happens. I could probably avoid this by manually overriding the assignment operator, but it'd make things a hot mess and I'd like to just avoid it entirely.

Comment: Then you should disable copying completely. Just delete the copy assignment operators.

Comment: If you can't copy the objects safely, as pointed out, disable the copying at the compilation stage.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I appreciate this advice, I'll give it a go. Wouldn't that break my above code though?

Comment: @Danny -- Yes, your code will break, but at the compilation stage, not at runtime.  Then you have to decide to either address all the places where you are doing the copy and figure out something else, bite the bullet and actually fix your copy-assignment operators, or just implement move semantics, if possible.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks Paul, I'm going to give it a whirl and see if removing the copy entirely is viable.

Comment: This sounds like a [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) violation. Make sure all constructors, assignment operators, and destructor are coded properly. Then the code shown will work properly.

Comment: @Danny -- Also make sure that *all* of the members are copied.  A lot of hard-to-find errors occur when an odd member or two are missing in the copying, thus the copies being made are half-baked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few options there, assuming your problem comes from the copy assignment:

#### Use a pointer type instead

Change `m_member` to be a `Foo*`, or better a `std::unique_ptr<Foo>`, to better match the previous behavior, and then do:

```
    m_member = std::make_unique<Foo>(var1, var2);
```

No copy, will still be destroyed at the end of your scope, and given the description of your problem, this might mean that your "Foo" resource is going to be more efficiently managed as a pointer.

You could also...

#### Define a move-assignment operator

Now this means you have to define [the big 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), but defining a move assignment operator will let you avoid the copy.

```
Foo& operator=(const Foo& other)
{
    // Copy the attributes you need to copy
    var1_ = other.var1_;
    var2_ = other.var2_;
    return *this;
}
```

This will effectively modify `Foo` in-place.

#### Fix the copy-assignment?

Now that's now really answering your question, but an unsuspecting developer would of course expect this to not crash, and it is highly possible that this problem will appear elsewhere, as copy-assignment is present a lot when writing code, and in standard algorithms. But there are multiple reason why this might not be able to, so I let you be the judge of that!

Comment: Thanks Adrien, this is helpful. I opted for a value declaration because I'd like to keep my buffers nice and close to each other in memory, but I'm thinking that cache coherency isn't going to be my performance bottleneck in this case, so I might just go down the pointer root after all.

Answer (score 2):

> strange crash ... which is happening because ... Which I've realized is performing a construction of Foo using var1 and var2, assigning this instantiation of Foo to m_member via a copy construction, and then is deleting the original instance.

If doing this causes a crash, then the design of the class of the member is broken. Probably (but I cannot be certain) due to failure to enforce a class invariant in the assignment operator which would be necessary to prevent the destructor from having undefined behaviour.

> Is there a way to avoid this behavior

If you need to assign the member, then you have to assign the member. If my suspicion is correct, you can fix the program by fixing the assignment operator.

If you don't need to assign the member, then you can avoid this behaviour by not assigning it. But fix the assignment operator anyway.

Since you haven't shown the class, I cannot know why it is broken, but most likely you should be looking at the destructor and the assignment operator and thinking about cases which might cause them to have undefined behaviour.

> Is there a way to avoid this behavior and have something akin to:
>
> ```
> m_member(var1, var2);
> ```

That is only possible when the member is initialised.